# JQuery load execute script onLoad

Tags: jquery, load, show-hide

I am using JQuery .load to load content onto a page. Problem is Jquery load strips all scripts so I can't activate a script that makes the loading wheel disappear.  So::

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#messageloader').hide();
});
</script>
```

Will not be executed. How would I go about this? The user has a series of options that determines what is loaded into the box. `Onclick` the loading wheel `#messageloader` appears. Once the new content is loaded in I want it to disappear.

Any ideas?

Marvellous

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's .load method has a completion callback function as the second parameter.  Put your load completion code in there.

```
$('#result').load('example.html', function() {
    $('#messageloader').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

on your load function you have a callback:

```
$('#messageloader').show();
$("#content").load("url", function() {
   $('#messageloader').hide();
});
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

To load a JavaScript file, try using [.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/), which is designed to load JavaScript.

You don't, however, need a new file to do what you want.  You just need callbacks as specified by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118869/jquery-load-execute-script-onload/5118895#5118895).